# How to debug the javascript functions in casperJS

Tags: javascript, debugging, phantomjs, casperjs

How can I debug the javascript functions (using `evaluate`) in CasperJS?

Is there anything similar to `alert()` which can be used here to print the values on the commandline as and when required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// add this to the top of the script
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo(msg);
})

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
  // and then add this to the evaluate to print a value
  console.log('Testing...');
})
```

To use this with a try-catch, use the following:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
  try {
    throw "Some error...";
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

Source: [CasperJS Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message)

Comment: basically am calling a javascript function inside the evaluate. What I want to do is to put some thing which displays variable value on the commandline similar to the alert() functionality.

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: @helix thanks it worked like charm. Can we also use try catch as in javascript inside the evaluate?? In that case how to show the error message